# Most General Unifier (Prolog)

Tags: prolog, unification

Have a quick question regarding m.g.u (most general unifier) in prolog.

We are asked what the m.g.u is of:

```
f(X, g(Y, h(Z))) = f(Z, g(P, h(a))).
```

With 2 possible answers

```
1. θ = {X/Z,Y/P,Z/a}.
2. θ = {X/a,Y/P,Z/a}.
```

I argued that the second answer was the most general unifier, however, it appears that the first answer is correct.

I have tried both substitutions and they both yield the same result, however the second answer was with fewer substitutions which is why I argued that it was the m.g.u

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
   +-----------X
   |
   |     +-----Y
   |     |
f--+--g--+
         |
         +--h--Z
         
         
   +-----------Z
   |
   |     +-----P
   |     |
f--+--g--+
         |
         +--h--a
```

Comment: Added diagrams for easier scanning.

Comment: Seriously these two subsitutions look each most general to me. Isn't it not the number of substitutions that counts, but whether the result is "most general", in the sense of "no variables have been needlessly replaced by terms"?

Comment: I used the number of substitutions to assume thats how they got the correct answer. Likewise, I'm confused as both substitutions result in the same output!

Comment: What is your definition of "most general unifier"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of an mgu is that there is no decomposition θ = λτ where λ,τ are non-trivial (not the identity, the names of freshly introduced variables don't matter). There exists a substitution of 1 that results in 2 (I can edit the solution later, if you don't find it) such that 2 can not be the most general substitution.

There's one more caveat: if you apply `θ = {X/Z,Y/P,Z/a}` to `X` you will end up with `Z`, not `a`. A substitution always happens simultaneously.

Comment: Yep, I've just been reading about simultaneous substitutions.. Monday afternoon, I need another coffee. Thanks again

Comment: Also took me a moment to see that that might be the source of the confusion :)